# To make sub-group and find its local maximum value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to calculate values in "AQ" Column which are taken from column "AN" as per arrow direction in column "D"
If the arrow is this "▲" in column "D", the value in column "AQ" should increase upward and if the arrow is this "▼", the value should increase downward.
I've been able to make the following code but not able to use this arrow. few sample is write down in column "AQ". Please help its been 5 hours I'm stuck with this problem

```
Sub SIZE()
Application.EnableEvents = False
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim destSht As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long, j As Long

  With Worksheets("final")
 lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  'if(k,"D")=Range("A1") then
   For i = 11 To lastrow + 1 'loop whole range (column AN)
    If .Cells(i, "AN") <> "" Then  'If column AN is not empty then
        For j = i To lastrow + 1 'Loop "group" range to find next empty cell. 
       Start from current loop i to last row and add one row to get to next empty cell.
            If .Cells(j, "AN") = "" Then 'When next empty cell is found (i.e. end of small group range) then apply formulas
                   .Cells(i, "AQ").Value = "=MAX(AN" & i & ":AN" & j - 1 & ")"
                Exit For
          End If
        Next j
    End If
  Next I
 End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What values are in A1 and B1?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz There are symbol of upward and downward arrows (Depends on values of G and H column, condition is shown in formula display bar in above picture

Comment: What I've done before with weird characters is use helper cells that contain them then check if the cell equals one of those cells. Otherwise if your using conditional formatting to colour if it's up or down then you could use `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to check against what colour it is rather than the symbol.

Comment: Do you mean if the arrow is down you want AQ to be a negative value and if it's up then be a positive value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub SIZE()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim destSht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set destSht = Worksheets("final")

With destSht
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 11 To lastrow + 1 'loop whole range (column AN)
        If .Cells(i, "AN") <> "" Then  'If column AN is not empty then
            For j = i To lastrow + 1 'Loop "group" range to find next empty cell.
                If .Cells(j, "AN") = "" Then 'When next empty cell is found (i.e. end of small group range) then apply formulas
                    If .Cells(i, "D").Value = .Cells(1, "B") Then 'Does it equal the down arrow?
                        .Cells(i, "AQ").Value = "=MAX(AN" & i & ":AN" & j - 1 & ")*-1" 'Make it negative if its down arrow
                    Else
                        .Cells(i, "AQ").Value = "=MAX(AN" & i & ":AN" & j - 1 & ")" 'otherwise positive
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

EDIT:

I have realised what you're trying to actually do. I believe I have it right. Have a go with this code and see if it does what you're after.

```
Sub SIZE()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim destSht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long

Set destSht = Worksheets("final")

With destSht
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 11 To lastrow
        If .Range("AN" & i) <> "" Then
            If .Range("D" & i) <> .Range("D" & i - 1) Then
                If .Range("D" & i) = .Range("A1") Then
                    For j = i To lastrow
                        If .Range("D" & j) <> .Range("D" & j + 1) Then
                            EndRow = j
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next j
                    .Range("AQ" & i).Value = "=MAX(AN" & i & ":AN" & j & ")"
                ElseIf .Range("D" & i) = .Range("B1") Then
                    StartRow = i
                    .Range("AQ" & i).Value = "=MAX(AN" & StartRow & ":AN" & i & ")"
                End If
            Else
                If .Range("D" & i) = .Range("A1") Then
                    .Range("AQ" & i).Value = "=MAX(AN" & i & ":AN" & j & ")"
                ElseIf .Range("D" & i) = .Range("B1") Then
                    .Range("AQ" & i).Value = "=MAX(AN" & StartRow & ":AN" & i & ")"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
    
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually what I'm trying to do is after finding a range through " j ". I want to further make a subrange of Upward arrow and downward arrow rows and calculate a max value for each group and it should be increasing order from CYAN Colored row for upward arrow as well as downward. Result got after applying the suggested code is shown in   "AQ" Column and the desired outcome is shown in "AR" column in the newly attached picture. Thanks

Comment: I've just realised what you're trying to achieve. Let me see.

Comment: @surendrachoudhary I've updated. See if that's what your wanting.

Comment: ..Works like Magic. Thanks a lot. ..Can you please suggest some resource to learn/practice this type of problem??

Comment: There isn't really anything in particular I learned from. Mostly this site every time I ran into a problem as well as the [Microsoft VBA Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-language-reference) helped me a lot. The main thing with your problem is you need 2 helper variables (one for up arrow, one for down) to store one side of the range while using i as the other side. I'm no expert with VBA, but I keep dabbling with it and slowly learning more and more.